# Not able to Json response from rest server

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, rest

Im trying to parse a Json response from a rest server using JavaScript and display the data.
The rest server works fine its just that i cant parse the data. I have looked at dozens of examples and from my understanding the code looks fine.
This is my first attempt at learning Ajax and if i fix this i can continue with my project.

This is the response

```
{"id":"1","author":"Bill Burke","title":"RESTful Java with JAX-RS","year":"2009"}
```

This is the server

```
@Path("/books") // JAX-RS annotation
public class BookResource {

@GET // JAX-RS annotation
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML })
@Path("/{bookId}")
public Book getBook(@PathParam("bookId") String id) {
    return BookDao.instance.getBook(Integer.parseInt(id));
}
}
```

This is the client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form to create a new resource</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getHTTPObject() {
    var xhr = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                xhr = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}

function grabFile(file) {
    var request = getHTTPObject();
    if (request) {
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            parseJ(request);
        };
        request.open("GET", file, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
}

function parseJ(request) {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 304) {

            var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = obj.id + " " + obj.author + " "
                    + obj.title + " " + obj.year;

        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a
    href="http://localhost:8080/Distributed_REST_booksServer/rest/books/1"
    onclick="grabFile(this.href); return false;">Book 1</a>
<br>
<div id="details"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[html console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdSKt.png)

[html console error after modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/880zI.png)

Comment: Your server is returning an error. Or at least HTML, because the first char is `<`.

Try:

`try{ var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText); } catch(e){ console.log(e,' on ',request.responseText); }` to verify, please, and post results.

Comment: i have added a new screenshot @henry700

Comment: Your server is returning XML, not JSON! Either configure the server properly or parse XML with your Javascript instead. For parsing of the XML you would need a library... Have you tried leaving only the JSON option on `@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML })`?

Answer (score 1):

Your server is returning XML, try to force it as JSON and maybe add an accept header to the request from the client.

Comment: i removed the MediaType for XML and left only Json and it worked.